# AWS Frontend Issue - Cannot Query Object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to find my record on the frontend using `pk=49` and I also want to filter if `course-number="TALF-50"`

I tried to use attribute name `metadata.saba.couse-number` and value `TALF-50` and doesn't work.

How do I specify the attribute name when it's a nested property from other objects?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible using the default viewer on the web-console. To filter based on a nested attribute value you will need to use PartiQL Editor which is also on the web-console and query using SQL style language.

[image: PartiQL]